# UITableView not showing on iPhone6 or 6+ simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to run my app on the iPhone 6 and 6+ simulator but my UITableViewController doesn't show the table, nothing. Just a blank screen. Works fine for iPhone 4, 4s 5 and 5s. What could be going wrong?

EDIT: Just discovered that the table is working fine, it's actually my data fetch to Parse.com that isn't working, code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;

    //if user item not set through login
    if(!self.currentUser) {

        __weak FriendsViewController *weakSelf = self;
        weakSelf.currentUser = [[appUser alloc] initWithParseUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [weakSelf.currentUser populateFriendsArrayWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL successful, NSError *error, BOOL addSelf, BOOL alreadyFriends) {

            NSLog(@"Array filled");
            NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[self.currentUser.friends count]);
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        }];//end populate method call

    }


}
```

for some reason the array is empty after the Parse.com call with the iPhone6 and 6+ but it's totally fine for iPhone4, 4s, 5, 5s! Seems so strange. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Can we see the storyboard. need to check your size class used

Comment: please see my question edit, realised that it was actually my Parse.com call that wasn't working...